# Is there any alternative tool to HTMLUnit for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory, htmlunit, dalvik

I'm having Java Heap Space (Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space). Tried increasing -XmsAm and -XmxBm paremeters in eclipse.ini still no use. Eclipse will throw error and close itself. BTW, my laptop has only 2GB RAM so I cannot the value increase too high.

Comment: I've just tested on another PC with 6GB RAM, no more java heap space issue, but I get this: 01-27 22:46:27.714: E/AndroidRuntime(10155): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>
I've added httpclient-4.1.2.jar in the library but still has this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit doesn't work with Android. But if you only need to parse some html, I would recommend JSoup!

Comment: what could one use for parsing dynamic content? (Jsoup can't handle Javascript)